# Issue with Maven in installing the Software

Tags: java, maven, mule-studio

I am new to Anypoint Studio and Maven.I have configured the Maven,but in my pom.xml i am getting the following compile time error.

```
Project build error: Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.mule.tools.maven:mule-app-maven-plugin:1.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact com.sun:tools:jar:1.5.0 at specified path C:\Program Files\Java\jre7/../lib/tools.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

It look's like your AnypoitStudio is point to the JRE rather than the JDK,

First of all I hope your **JAVA_HOME** path is pointing to the right folder  for example  `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26` as well as you have defined it in **PATH**  correctly i.e till `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\bin`.

If that's all correct...

Then you can check out the Anypoint Studio configurations by going in **Windows > Preferences** in it select **Java > Installed JREs** check it out how it is configured over there, is it point to the required path or not ?

Mine looks likes as following and I am on ubuntu so set your configurations according to Windows, remember the path should point to the JDK not the JRE

[image]